# Issue creating SKPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, skphysicsbody

I have a plank, which undergoes constant vertical velocity changes. Therefore setting it's dynamic property to false will not do since `physicsBody.velocity` will not work.

```
plank.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(plankWidth, plankHeight))
plank.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
plank.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
```

I also have a ball that rests on the plank:

```
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: frame.width*CGFloat(1/Float(NumberOfPlanks+1))*0.2)
ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true
ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = false
```

This ball must be affected by gravity, rest on the plank, but not affect it's motion. This ball must also be able to undergo `applyForce` and `applyImpulse`.

Is there a simple way of accomplishing my goal? Thanks :)